# For Loop not executing correctly

Tags: python

I am running a for loop that need to run 100 times. The for loop in turn has an if/else condition. On executing the for loop, the if/else condition is working fine and stopping at the end of else condition, but not looping through the for loop. I tried several ways, but am not able to get the loop working.

```
for loop in range(100):
    if not fb_buttons:
        refresh.click()
        print("refreshed")
    else:
        for button in fb_buttons:
            button.click()
            driver.implicitly_wait(3)
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
            time.sleep(3)
            driver.close()
            print("popup closed")
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
            continue
```

I am expecting the loop to run 100 times, but it stops after running one time.

Comment: if youre not gonna use the incrementer, don't name it. Use `_`

Comment: I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If fb_buttons happens to be an iterator (e.g. `fb_buttons = reversed(buttonList)` ), once it reaches the end, your first test `if not fb_buttons:` will return False (because the iterator object exists) and the for loop in the `else:` block will not process any items (because the iterator has reached the end). So the loop will actually run 100 times but will do nothing.

You could verify this by adding `fb_buttons = list(fb_buttons)` before the `if not fb_buttons` line.

You could also reorganize your code a little to use an `else:` statement on the `for button in fb_buttons:` loop:

```
for _ in range(100):
    for button in fb_buttons:
        button.click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.close()
        print("popup closed")
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    else:
        refresh.click()
        print("refreshed")
```

If your `fb_buttons` variable is an iterator, the logic will only go through the fb_buttons loop once unless `fb_buttons` is reset by refresh.click().

*BTW, the `continue` instruction at the end of a loop has no effect.*

*Also, you could use `_` instead of `loop` on that first line : 
`for _ in range(100):`.   It is not necessary to define a variable for a value you're not going to use (this is what @alec935's comment meant to say).*

Comment: @Alan, I have tested with your code, it is working as expected till refresh after clicking all the links in if condition, however, the for loop still did not execute, any ideas why it stopped

Comment: There is possibly a function that does not return. Try adding an unconditional print("main loop pass") inside the `for _ in range(100):` loop.  If you don't see it print 100 times then the loop is jammed on a function that does not return.  If it does print 100 times, then something is going on elsewhere in your code.